# How to perform Right click operation in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I have one *rect* tag as mentioned below, I am able to locate its position but now when i perform right click on it it can not perform any operation.
Is there any solution for it?

```css
<rect class="" stroke-dasharray="" vector-effect="" height="22" width="22" y="0" x="0" visibility="visible" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,255)" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,255)" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 169 -11)"></rect>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform right click operation in Selenium using [`Actions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class. Here's a sample of it -

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
actions.contextClick(WebElement).build().perform(); //pass your rect WebElement as an argument
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
 action.contextClick(productLink).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

If you want to click on any specified webElement, 
change `productLink to driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));`

Comment: i am using down arrow for selecting values,